# MySQL procedure to add multiple entries and get auto incremented id

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create **MySQL procedure** to simultaneously add entries to multiple tables and later entries should include auto incremented id from the first entry.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE my_procedure (value1 INT(10), value2 VARCHAR(255), value3 TEXT)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO table1 (column1, column2, column3) VALUES (value1, value2);
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3) VALUES (AUTO_INCREMENTED_VALUE_FROM_TABLE_1, value3)
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

What will be the correct syntax to do this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html)

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE my_procedure (value1 INT(10), value2 VARCHAR(255), value3 TEXT)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table1 (column2, column3) VALUES (value1, value2);
  INSERT INTO table2 (column2, column3) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), value3)
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Works like a charm ! Danke Schön :)